# Why I can't load mnist dataset with load_data() method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I used this line of code to load the mnist dataset and I got it from tensorflow documentation.
`(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = load_data(path='mnist.npz')`

But when I executed the file I got an error with certificate

The error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist_degit.py", line 18, in <module>
    (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = load_data(path='mnist.npz')
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Desktop/ComputerVision_project/DigitRecognize/digit_recognize_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/mnist.py", line 62, in load_data
    '731c5ac602752760c8e48fbffcf8c3b850d9dc2a2aedcf2cc48468fc17b673d1')
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Desktop/ComputerVision_project/DigitRecognize/digit_recognize_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 267, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
(trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

Comment: Please let me know your python version. I think this is not about Tensorflow problem. It's about ssl certification.

Comment: I use python version 3.7

Comment: Try this command. 
"openssl s_client -connect github.com:443".
And let me know your response

Comment: it's not fit to the comment so i split it to 3 parts

Comment: ```Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:```

Comment: ```SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    Session-ID: AD61E9AC5AD4DEA2CABF4BCE734C232E37D4F055B82C432BE319E7B5235687C0
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: B03C121A9E8935D2DCF8B036A61550C0F0026CB4FB023C0A2025006EB57F246E
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
  ```

Comment: ```Start Time: 1591243593
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
closed```

Comment: Then try to execute this command.
"import requests
response = requests.get("https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz")
print(response.status_code)"

Comment: It just gave me an arrow with nothing

Comment: Is it because of the python version?

Comment: Should I change the python version to 3.6?

Comment: What can I do now

Comment: I use python version 3.7 with tensorflow 2.2.0 and keras 0.23.1

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: You could execute command "pip freeze > requirements.txt", to open requirements.txt file and see if "certifi" package is installed in python.

Comment: Sir finally i can work with mnist dataset now but I have to create a new virtual environment and with python 3.6 and with old version of tensorflow and keras from 2017

Comment: Thanks you for spending your time with me

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')
```

Or

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.compat.v1.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```